# base.SendAsync -How symmetrical execution was done?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, sendasync

[In asp.net  - using Message Handlers](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/04/04/webapi-tip-7-beautiful-message-handlers.aspx) - I can customize the request/response by adding message handlers.

So, a request comes in , going through multiple message handlers and then the response is back through the same handlers( in opposite direction).

[image]

So, for example :  if I attach 2 message handlers :  *(yes I know, async/await is preferred, but that's from a book)*

```
public class CustomMessageHandler1 : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("CustomMessageHandler1 request invoked");
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
                   .ContinueWith(task =>
                                      {
                                      Debug.WriteLine("CustomMessageHandler1 response invoked");
                                      var response = task.Result;
                                      return response;
                                      });
    }
}


public class CustomMessageHandler2 : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("CustomMessageHandler2 request invoked");
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
                   .ContinueWith(task => 
                                      {
                                      Debug.WriteLine("CustomMessageHandler2 response invoked");
                                      var response = task.Result;
                                      return response;
                                 });
    }
}
```

Let's not forget to register those in global.asax :

```
var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new CustomMessageHandler1());
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new CustomMessageHandler2());
```

And the result is :

[image]

As you can see , like I said and [like this article says](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/04/04/webapi-tip-7-beautiful-message-handlers.aspx) : The execution is symmetrical.

**Great.**

But then I thought to myself - **how** did they do that symmetrical execution?

So I succeed creating  my own demo of symmetrical execution using continuation:

```
void Main()
{
 Method1() ;    
}

  public async  Task  Method1 ()
  {
   Console.WriteLine ("Method_1"); //alias to request
   await Method2();
   Console.WriteLine ("Finished Method_1");  //alias to response
  }


 public async Task  Method2 ()
 {
  Console.WriteLine ("Method_2");  //alias to request
  await Task.FromResult("...");//dummy
  Console.WriteLine ("Finished Method_2");  //alias to response

 }
```

And the result was indeed symetrical :

```
Method_1
Method_2
Finished Method_2
Finished Method_1
```

But in my code `Method1` **called** `Method2` and **that's why it worked !**.

**But** in the *first* code above - they do NOT call each other ! it's like something is invoking only the *first* part ( before the `ContinueWith`) from each method , and then run the *second* part( after the `ContinueWith`) from each method.

Something like :

[image]

So i've look at the [reference source  for `base.Sendasync`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Net.Http/System/Net/Http/DelegatingHandler.cs) :  But couldn't find how `base.Sendasync` is doing this symmetrical execution

**Question**

How does  `base.Sendasync` is doing that symmetrical execution  without having one method calling the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the console-appified Web API pipeline for you.

```
abstract class BaseHandler // HttpHandler
{
    public abstract Task MyMethodAsync();
}

abstract class Handler : BaseHandler // MessageHandler
{
    public Handler InnerHandler { get; set; }

    public override Task MyMethodAsync()
    {
        if (this.InnerHandler != null)
            return this.InnerHandler.MyMethodAsync();
        else
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}

class Handler1 : Handler
{
    public override async Task MyMethodAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method_1"); //alias to request
        await base.MyMethodAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Finished Method_1");  //alias to response
    }
}

class Handler2 : Handler
{
    public override async Task MyMethodAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method_2"); //alias to request
        await base.MyMethodAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Finished Method_2");  //alias to response
    }
}

class LastHandler : Handler
{
    public override async Task MyMethodAsync()
    {
        // Does nothing
        await base.MyMethodAsync();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Handler> handlers = new List<Handler>();
        // You do this when you add the handler to config
        handlers.Add(new Handler1());
        handlers.Add(new Handler2());

        // This part is done by HttpClientFactory
        Handler pipeline = new LastHandler();

        handlers.Reverse();
        foreach (var handler in handlers)
        {
            handler.InnerHandler = pipeline;
            pipeline = handler;
        }

        pipeline.MyMethodAsync().Wait();
    }
}
```

Comment: Very helpful , shows exactly the chaining... but how could I know it from the reference source ? ALL I see is abstracts without implementations, so how did you find it :-) ?  I was looking at DelegatingHandler

Comment: The first component in Web API pipeline is `HttpServer`. https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/HttpServer.cs. In `Initialize`, `HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline` is called that builds the pipeline. https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/0ee98f84b41b6bef6bde6945e2797de9dac7d48a/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/HttpClientFactory.cs. `HttpControllerHandler` calls `HttpServer.SendAsync`. https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/0ee98f84b41b6bef6bde6945e2797de9dac7d48a/src/System.Web.Http.WebHost/HttpControllerHandler.cs

Comment: DelegatingHandler does not do much but calling SendAsync on the inner handler. Pipeline is built in HttpServer and HttpControllerHandler calls HttpServer. HttpControllerHandler is a web-hosting concept BTW.

Comment: PS how can [it be a source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Net.Http/System/Net/Http/DelegatingHandler.cs) if it doesn't compile ?( for example : `protected DelegatingHandler();` has no body...)

Answer (score 3):

Each delegating handler is aware of its "next" handler, and `DelegatingHandler.SendAsync` *does* call `SendAsync` on the next ("inner") handler. You can think of it like a linked list, as such:

```
public abstract class MyDelegatingHandler
{
  private readonly MyDelegatingHandler _next;

  public MyDelegatingHandler(MyDelegatingHandler next = null)
  {
    _next = next;
  }

  public virtual Task SendAsync()
  {
    if (_next == null)
      return Task.FromResult(0);
    return _next.SendAsync();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but where is the _chaining_ is done ? can you please elaborate your code to show how chaining is done ?  if there's another `MyDelegatingHandler` implementer - it has its own `_next` so I dont see where is the link here.

Comment: It's being done in (or by) `config.MessageHandlers.Add`. To confirm that, try adding them in the opposite order.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: The actual `DelegatingHandler` just has an `InnerHandler` property that is set by the framework. In my example code, it's set by the constructor.